# R cmd check Latex error: FATAL pdflatex - GUI framework cannot be initialized

Tags: r, cmd, latex, pdflatex, miktex

I am checking my package and this is actually the last remaining problem. The pdf file cannot be compiled and the logfile tells me

```
2015-10-15 14:17:47,430+0200 INFO  pdflatex - running 'initexmf --quiet --update-fndb' to refresh the file name database
2015-10-15 14:17:50,276+0200 FATAL pdflatex - GUI framework cannot be initialized.
2015-10-15 14:17:50,276+0200 FATAL pdflatex - Info: 
2015-10-15 14:17:50,276+0200 FATAL pdflatex - Source: Libraries\MiKTeX\UI\Qt\mikuiqt.cpp
2015-10-15 14:17:50,276+0200 FATAL pdflatex - Line: 50
```

Any idea where the problem could be?

Comment: Related/cross-network duplicate: [How can I fix the error “GUI framework cannot be initialized” with TeXnicCenter and MiKTeX?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/27138/5764)

Comment: Werner seems to be right. I faced exactly the same problem as Christine Blume, and I solved it via Werner's method in Windows 8.1 and Revolution R Enterprise environment: "Start - bottom arrow - MikTex Settings - MiKTeX Options" and chose "Yes" (not "Ask me first") for the option "Install missing packages on-the-fly". I advice doing these for both "MikTex Settings" and "MikTex Settings(Admin)".

Answer (score 16):

I had this same issue, but for the newest versions of Miktex, **mo.exe** does not exist, and is replaced by the Miktex console. If you open it, go into settings and change the package on-the-fly setting from "Ask Me" to "Always", then the packages will install. If you do "Never" instead, then you'll have to do the individual package installation described by @topchef.

[image: October 2021 Screenshot of the MiKTeX Console Settings tab with "Always" selected]

Answer (score 11):

This is known problem wit MikTex 2.9 when pdflatex encounters error

```
GUI framework cannot be initialized.
```

(found on my Windows 7 system in the file *~\AppData\Local\MiKTeX\2.9\miktex\log*)

So far, I can offer following sequence of actions to remedy this:

1. In Windows Command prompt go to MiKTeX bin folder (e.g. *C:\Program Files (x86)\MiKTeX 2.9\miktex\bin*) and run utility **mo.exe**;
2. In General tab change 'Install missing packages on-the-fly:' option to No (this will disable GUI and error above won't be happening again);
3. Run R CMD that calls latex converter again (in my case

   ```
   R CMD Rd2pdf man/
   ```

again to see new errors;

4. This time miktex won't complaint about GUI - instead it will be missing packages with error like this

   ```
   ! LaTeX Error: File `inconsolata.sty' not found.
   ```
5. Start MiKTeX package manager (again from **mo.exe** Packages tab) and install missing package one at the time by repeating steps 3.-5.

This might be not most effective way of fixing this so I appreciate corrections or alternative solutions.

Comment: For me the issue was that it was set to ask for packages to be installed.  By selecting automatic, all errors disappeared and I managed to knit a pdf as expected.

Answer (score 3):

I ran into this problem just... A very easy solution for me that allowed me **not** to renege on the `install on the fly` option is to install [TexStudio](https://www.texstudio.org/), open your `.tex` file in there, and compile it: you will be able to install all your `MikTex` packages on the fly as desired and retain control over what gets installed.

Comment: +1. Thanks that has solved my problem. It seems that RStudio is not able to prompt for package installation when needed.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem compiling Knit to PDF of a R markdown file in R studio. Once I changed from "Ask me" to "Always" in the MikTex console setting (see the screenshot posted above [Cara Wogsland]) it compiled without errors.